# Checking is the answer of a randomly created addition is correct in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, random

So I have just ran into a problem that I cannot check if the value, entered by a user is correct or not, in a randomly created addition.

I have already tried to change the `int` value to `bool` but it did not work the way it was intended to, resulting me not being able to check the result with the `if` statement.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Counting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int e;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Solve the following math problem!");
                Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(50) + "+" + rnd.Next(50));
                    
                Console.Write("Your answer: ");
                e = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                
            }          
            Console.ReadKey();    
        }
    }
}
```

How should I get it working?

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the results of the 2 randomly generated values or you cannot check later, if the solution is correct.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int e;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int r1 = rnd.Next(50);
    int r2 = rnd.Next(50);

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Solve the following math problem!");
    Console.WriteLine(r1 + "+" + r2);

    Console.Write("Your answer: ");
    e = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (e == r1 + r2)
    {
      //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: But definitely learn how to use [TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) instead, as you can write more robust code and error checking with that.